# How to create a html table from array of objects in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to create an HTML table from an array of objects I receive from an API call. I am using react. Here is the relevant code

```
  return(
    </Container>
      {((demoLedgerEntries.length > 0) &&
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr><td>Title demo</td><td>Title demo</td><td>Title demo</td></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr><td>itemdemo1</td><td>itemdemo1</td><td>itemdemo1</td></tr>
            {demoLedgerEntries.forEach((item) => {
              return(<tr><td>{item.name}</td> </tr>)
              })
            }
            <tr><td>itemdemo2</td><td>itemdemo2</td><td>itemdemo2</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        )
      }
    </Container>
  )
```

The demoLedgerEntries is an array of objects as follows.

```
setDemoLedgerEntries([
  { name: 'Player 1', score: 10 },
  { name: 'Player 2', score: 7 },
  { name: 'Player 3', score: 3 }]
);
```

The resulting table only has the head row, the first row and the last row. The forEach loop for the array is not producing any  elements. How do I modify the code to make it work?

Comment: `forEach` in JavaScript will execute the specified callback for each input, but does not have a return value. You probably want `map` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Hamms said in his comment you can use map to go through elements of `demoLadgerEntries` array, so your code will look something like this:

```
{demoLedgerEntries.map((item) => (
    <tr>
       <td>{item.wagerAmount}</td> 
    </tr>
))}
```

or maybe this is what you want:

```
<tr>
   {demoLedgerEntries.map((item) => (
      <td>{item.wagerAmount}</td> 
   ))}
</tr>
```

Also, I don't see `wagerAmount` in elements of your `demoLadgerEntries` array.

Comment: This worked correctly. wagerAmount was an attribute of the original object. I had cut down the object for readability.